# @DataJpaTest loads KafkaConfiguration and fails test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, integration-testing, spring-test

```
@DataJpaTest
class DataJpaVerificationTest {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate template;

    @Test
    public void testTemplate() {
        assertThat(template).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

When I run this test I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
> Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'kafkaConfig' defined in file
> [***\config\KafkaConfig.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaProperties'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

where `KafkaConfig` class is a part of my application (app read data from `Kafka` and saves data to DB) and looks like:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KafkaConfig {
    private final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

    @Bean
    public Properties consumerProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.putAll(this.kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties());
        return props;
    }
}
```

Based on information that I googled about `DataJpaTest` annotation:

> created application context will not contain the whole context needed
> for our Spring Boot application, but instead only a “slice” of it
> containing the components needed to initialize any JPA-related
> components like our Spring Data repository.

So the question is: why `Spring` tries to load to the context `Kafka` specific bean for `DataJpaTest`?